# Send a message and upload a file in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, file, upload

I have form that allows users to send me a message on my email, but I want it that when a user fills the form and chooses a file the file gets uploaded to the server and the message gets sent to me. I did do the message part but I couldn't get the file uploaded. here is my code: 
Index page:

```
<form action="mail.php" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type="text" class="feedback-input" id="firstname" name="firstname"       placeholder="First Name" size="30" required="">
<br/>
<input type="text" class="feedback-input" id="lastname" name="lastname"     placeholder="Last Name" size="30" required="">
<br/>
<input type="email" class="feedback-input" id="title" name="title" placeholder="E-mail"       size="30" required="">
<br/>
<textarea name="message" class="feedback-input" placeholder="What can I help you with?"   style="height: 150px;" required=""></textarea><br/>
<br/>

<input type="file" name="file" id="file" placeholder=" " tabindex="1" required/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="Submit" value="Send">
```

and this is the mail.php file:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$formcontent=" From: $firstname $lastname \n Email Address: $title \n IP: $ip \n\n                         Description : $message";
$recipient = "myemail@yahoo.com";
$subject = "New Message!!";
$mailheader = "From: $title \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
header("Location: www.mythankyoupage.com");
die();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your file upload should be based on this
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp
Please comment if you get stuck somewhere and I'll gladly help! :)